# How to use Progressbar in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, progress-bar

I'm really stuck on this. I searched a lot in the net but actually nothing helped me. In my view I have one button and the progressbar, when the user click on button it does different work and after increase the *CurrentProgress*.

But it shows to user only in the end of Work the 100% in the end and is not what i want. I would like that eachtime that the *CurrentProgress* is increased it shows and display to the view.

The controls in the view are those:

```
<Button x:Name="Generate" Content="Generate" />
<ProgressBar  Value="{Binding Path=CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" Width="80" Height="15"/>
```

And this is the code in the ViewModel

```
private int currentProgress;
public int CurrentProgress
{
    get { return currentProgress; }
    set
    {
        if (currentProgress == value)       
            return;

        currentProgress = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentProgress);
    }
}

List<Article> articles;


public void Generate()
{
    foreach (var art in articles)
    {       
        //[..]
        //Insert article                    

        inserted++;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>updateProgress(inserted));                    
    }

}


private void updateProgress(int Analyzed)
{
    if (Analyzed != 0)
    {
        int percentage = 100 * Analyzed / articles.Count;
        CurrentProgress = percentage;
    }   
}
```

How to fix the issue?. Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: You need to execute your work on a background thread and update your progress on the UI thread - you are doing this the other way round, so your UI will be blocked until it finishes.

Comment: As a side note, all values you are calculating `percentage` with are ints, so they'll all be rounded to the nearest whole number. You probably have to cast that to something with decimals

Comment: When you do work on the UI thread, the UI isn't redrawn until the work is complete.  That's because the thread is doing the work, not updating the UI.  That's an important concept to understand if you're going to be developing more complex applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole content of the "Generate" method inside a task. Then you don't need to do anything special to update the progress since the "NotifyPropertyChanged" events are automatically marshalled at UI level by WPF.
Something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    foreach (var art in articles)
    {       
        //[..]
        //Insert article                    

        inserted++;

        updateProgress(inserted);                    
    }
}
```